# How do I move from python 2.6 to 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, boto

How do I install boto module in python 2.7.6 (manually installed) rather than installing it in 2.6.6 (CentOS system default). I tried to install boto using *pip install boto* which gets installed in under older version of python. How do I configure it so that python 2.7.6 will be able to use boto?

Comment: Are you able to install `pip2.7`?

Comment: @Kupiakos Thanks. pip2.7 installed the required modules.